# How to cast a pointer to an int in c ( to get its ascii value )

Tags: c

I have a pointer ( *ascii ) which a pointer to a char and I want it is value as an int in order to make it an if statement like

```
if ( ascii == 32 || ((ascii > 96) && (ascii < 123)) {

}
```

This is not working, i would appreciate help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is not working because you are checking the value of the pointer (the memory address) not the value of the thing being pointed at. Remember a pointer is an address, you have to **dereference** it to get the value at that address.

Once dereferenced, you can simply do a comparison with a char type to those values:

```
 char ascii_char = *ascii;

 if ( ascii_char == 32 || ((ascii_char > 96) && (ascii_char < 123)) 
 {

 }
```

Comment: Beginner's guide: the pointer is your finger. The char is the moon. Do not confuse the two ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Just put a * before the variable name

```
if ( *ascii == 32 || ((*ascii > 96) && (*ascii < 123)) {

}
```

or just assign it to another variable and use it instead

```
int a = *ascii
if ( a == 32 || ((a > 96) && (a < 123)) {

}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you go for ASCII value?

Following would be more readable way:

char ascii_char = *ascii;

if ( ascii_char == ' ' || ((ascii_char >= 'a') && (ascii_char <= 'z'))

{

}

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do the trick

```
int asciiNum = (int)*ascii;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not referring to comparing just the first char but the number stored in that ascii pointer then use atoi() function to convert the char array to a number and then compare.

Comment: No it is part of standard C library libc

Comment: It's itoa which is non-standard. Also std::iota in the SGI STL is not in standard C++. The two are easily typoed.